# Why testing return value from fgrep always false in below code?

Tags: test, exit-status

I have the below script to find missing items from fileA compared to fileB and write to fileC

```
script.sh fileA fileB fileC
```

script.sh:

```
rm $3
while IFS="" read -r inputline; do

fgrep -q \""$inputline"\" $1  
if [ 1 -eq $? ]; then
    echo \""$inputline"\" >>$3
fi
done <$2
```

I see everything in fileB getting dumped to fileC, i'm missing somethig basic. (aix 6, bash)

ps: files have trailing spaces and it matters in comparison

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question, but perhaps [comm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comm) does what you need.

Comment: Better to see your `fileB` and `fileA` to sea `inputline` but are you sure that  all lines in `fileA` have quotes?

Comment: @Costas im pretty sure it's not beacuse of file contents. and no quotes in the files, one set of quotes immediately surrounding the variable is to prevent trialing spaces getting stripped off. next set (escaped quotes) are for having the string enclosed in the fgrep call. also i verified in the tasks i can see    fgrep "xyz   " fileA

Comment: Try  to deal without extra quotes: `if ! grep -Fq "$inputline" $1 ; then`

Comment: I checked running processes while script is running and it shows {fgrep "xyz        " fileA }-with spaces - which is exactly what i want. without 'extra' quotes it evaluates to {fgrep xyz        fileA}, which is as good as {fgrep "xyz" fileA}

Comment: One pair of quotes is enough. Check `while IFS="" read -r line ; do echo "=$line=" ; done < fileB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
rm "$3"
while IFS="" read -r inputline
do
    grep -Fq "$inputline" "$1" && echo "$inputline" >> "$3"
done < "$2"
```

Comment: below one worked! thanks! but any idea why the if+test method is acting different?  `#!/usr/bin/bash

echo "" > "$3"
while IFS="" read -r inputline; do

fgrep -q \""$inputline"\" "$1" && echo \""$inputline"\" >>"$3"

done <$2`

Comment: `If+test` should act the same. Problem can be in file's names quoting. Additionally `Direct  invocation  as  either egrep or fgrep is deprecated`